# Access rights issue in MAC

Tags: mac-osx

I have a Mac machine running Mac OS Version 10.6.6.

I have added my mac machine to a domain controller (which runs Windows version of server) and allow users from domain controller to login.

Because of our server migration, we removed the mac machine from old domain controller and added it to the new domain controller.

Users in the old domain controller are copied to new domain controller.

When I login into mac (which is added to new domain controller) with the domain controller user credentials, I was not able to access my desktop folders and any other folders in my users directory.

It says "The folder Desktop can't be opened because you don't have permission its contents"

Answer (score 1):

This will need to move to serverfault.
Rebinding the client to the server may well do the trick. Also worth checking the options when binding such as the option to have the home folder stored locally rather than on the server.

Oh and check DNS, it's a surprising what odd errors can be caused by DNS

Answer (score 0):

I presume we're talking about an Active Directory domain?  How did you migrate users between servers, and did it preserve the user's GUIDs?  When a Mac is bound to Active Directory, it uses a hash of the user's GUID as the unix ID number for the user (which is used, among other things, to track file ownership).  Thus, if the user's GUID changes, so does their UID, and they don't own their files (and home directory) anymore.  You can check this by logging in as a local user on the Mac (hopefully you have a local admin?  Otherwise, this'll get complicated to fix...):

```
$ ls -ln /Users
total 0
drwxrwxrwt   5 0          0          170 Jul 25  2010 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 21 501        20         714 Feb 22 11:24 ladmin
drwxr-xr-x+ 13 875491302  759086213  442 Feb 22 13:52 fred
```

In the above example, the "fred" folder is owned by UID #875491302, and assigned to group #759086213.  You can then use the "id" command to check the user's current UID and group membership:

```
$ id fred
uid=875491302(fred) gid=759086213(EXAMPLE\domain users) groups=759086213(EXAMPL
E\domain users),402(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),62(netaccounts),12(everyone),
403(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),404(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3)
```

Here, the IDs match up: fred's UID is 875491302, and 759086213 is the EXAMPLE\domain users group.  If they didn't match up, you can reset the ownership to fred's new UID by running a command like:

```
$ sudo chown -R "fred:EXAMPLE\domain users" /Users/fred
```